# how can i lock a class while other method running? (with timeout)

Tags: node.js, locking

I want to wait while a class other method running, current solution:

```
      async waitForUnlock(ms: number) {
        if (!this.locked) return

        const start = new Date().getTime();
        let time = 0;

        while (time < ms) {
            if (!this.locked) {
                return;
            }
            const end = new Date().getTime();
            time = end - start;
        }
        throw new Error(`timeout ${ms} ms. The queue is locked.`)
    }
```

example usage:

```
    async undoCommand(numberOfCommands: number = 1, timeout: number = 1000): Promise<void> {
        await this.waitForUnlock(timeout)
    // ....
```

it's oke? is there a better solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "lock"? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Wait while a class  method running. While running the this.locked = true, when done loceked = false.. (the problem is 2 async function running at the same time)

Comment: Async functions usually don't run at the same time. There is no multithreading unless you opt into it. And in the occasions where two async functions do intersect, a timed lock is unlikely to be of much help. Might even lead to further problems.

Comment: btw thanks for answer.. here is the context:  [link](https://github.com/MaurerKrisztian/command-pattern/blob/main/lib/CommandQueue.ts)

Comment: I want to avoid to undoCommands and redoCommands make a conflict

Comment: Here are two task queue implementations that wait for the previous task's promise to complete before invoking the next task: https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue and https://github.com/rkaw92/esdf/blob/0.2.0-new/utils/QueueProcessor.js